# Count distinct substring in jpql

Tags: hibernate, count, substring, jpql

I want to count in jpql (hibernate) number of distinct substrings, but

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(t.id, 1, 2)) FROM MyEntity t
```

fails with syntax error
Any idea how can I achieve it **wiht single jpql without criteria api** and with a single result (getSingleResult()).

Edit: If it is not possible is also an info for me. I know it is possible with criteria api or native query or counting rows of a grouped by selection. So I'll just use the .size() if a single result row is not possible.

Comment: You might have to use a criteria query here.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was afraid so... Well thanks anyway for the info.

Comment: You can always do a raw query...this might be what I would do in this case.

Comment: Yes, I know. Well I ended up with calling size() on a grouped by select: GROUP BY SUBSTRING(t.id, 1, 2)